# Requires a permission that's already there?

Tags: java, android, xml

I was trying to launch an activity from a different project, but when I run it, it crashes and tells me I need permission. I already added a `<uses-permission>` so I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help?

Manifest code for the activity that creates the intent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.permissionslab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!--  TODO - add uses-permission elements -->
    <uses-permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

Manifest code for activity that needs to be started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.dangerousapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" ></permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:permission="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
            android:name=".DangerousActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />        
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<uses-permission>` needs to be in the manifest for the app that contains the "dangerous" activity.

Comment: So basically I add the `uses-permission` into the manifest of the activity that is being started?  **EDIT:** It doesn't work, same error

Comment: Weird, I ran it again and it started working. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you clean the project before running.  Exactly when you need to clean seems to have changed a few times, and I don't know if it was Eclipse or the Android SDK that changed, so now I always clean out of an abundance of caution.